# What should be written inside the connection string when migrating SQL db to Azure with VS2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, connection-string, localdb

[image]

The situation is that I want to deploy my local db created in VS2015 into Azure.
Looking into the attached image, what should I write inside the connection string?

Comment: You can get the connection string from the Azure portal

Comment: @ErikEJ I also required to change the web.config. What should be changed?

Comment: Do not rely on web.config, use App Service settings for cloud, but otherwise same connection string